# Rails 5 - Ordering by created_at but show nulls last of another column

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Using Rails 5, with PostgreSQL.

What I am trying to do:

I have a `Service` model, with `created_at` and `base_price` attributes.

I would like to order them by creation date but if the base price is `nil`, then keep those at the bottom, also ordered by creation.

I have tried something like this:

```
Service.order('created_at DESC, base_price NULLS LAST')
```

but this does not achieve what I am looking for.

Any help would be appreciated. I know there is a similar question, but there is no explanation and I am having a hard time implementing it.
Thanks!

Comment: Edit your post and reveal what breed of database you use. SQLite? MySQL?

Comment: @phlip PostgreSQL, apologies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a case statement to specify all base_price non-null as 1 and all base_price null as 2 so they get sorted as two groups, 1 and 2.  Within the groups you can sort by created_at descending.

```
Service.order('CASE WHEN base_price IS NULL THEN 2 ELSE 1 END, created_at DESC')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like following

```
SELECT field1, field2,
  CASE
    WHEN base_price IS NOT NULL THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END 
  AS field3
FROM services
ORDER BY (field3 DESC, created_at DESC)
```